# Combine Columns in CSV file using JAVA

Tags: java, csv, edit

I want to combine columns in csv file using java 
here in this file i want combine first two columns "Product No"  and "Product Name".

This is My CSV File

```
 Productno,Productname,Price,Quantity
 1,java,300,5
 2,java2,500,10
 3,java3,1100,120
```

Here is My Code

```
private void parseUsingOpenCSV(String filename) 

{
   CSVReader reader;
   FileWriter out = null;
   CSVWriter outt;
   try 
  {
  reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
  String[] row;

   try {
    out= new FileWriter("E:/data/test/newww.csv");
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   try {
    while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) 
        {
            // display CSV values


            System.out.println(row[i]);
            String com = row[i];

            out.write(com); 
        }

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}finally{
  if (out != null) {
      try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}   
}
```

By using this code i get output is below

```
Product No
Product Name
Price
1
java
300
2
java2
500
3
java3
1100
```

But I want Output like this....

```
 ProductnoProductname,Price,Quantity
 1java,300,5
 2java2,500,10
 3java3,1100,120
```

Comment: Try to use print instead of println

Comment: using print i get output like this "Product NoProduct NamePrice1java3002java25003java31100"

Comment: i want combine columns not all data

Comment: as you saw in the post below, add a println after each iteration

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) 
    {
        // display CSV values


        System.out.print(row[i]);
        String com = row[i];

        out.write(com); 
    }
 System.out.println();
}
```

this breaks the output only after ove SV line is writen

Comment: You Should add the commas easily.

Comment: can u tell me  exact what can i do?

Comment: This is really basic stuff, looks like you should learn java for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this:** `System.out.println(row[i]);`
**With:** `System.out.print(row[i]+" ");`

And as *Dr. Y* mentioned, add `System.out.println();` after `for loop`

```
while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) 
    {
        // display CSV values


        System.out.print(row[i]+", "); // here is the commas 
        String com = row[i];

        out.write(com); 
    }
 System.out.println();
}
```

**Useful links for you:**

[Difference between print and println in java](https://www.inf.unibz.it/~calvanese/teaching/04-05-ip/lecture-notes/uni02/node4.html)

[How does System.out.ptintln() work ?](http://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/java/how-system-out-println-work-in-java.php)

Comment: i use this also but i get output like this "Product NoProduct NamePrice1java3002java25003java31100"

Comment: Well - System.out.print(row[i]+" ");