# How to copy specific columns of two files into one file in Java?

Tags: java, merge, text-files

I have 2 text files with different size that I want to copy/merge into one new file with different column name and only specific column will be copied.

For example:

```
//file1.txt
Source  Target  Value
A       B       0.5
A       C       0.1
B       A       0.25
C       B       0.05
C       D       0.25
C       E       0.5
D       A       0.4
E       A       0.75

//file2.txt
Source  Target  Value
A       B       0.3
B       C       0.5
B       A       0.75
C       B       0.01
C       D       0.25
D       C       0.5
D       E       0.25
E       A       0.4
E       C       0.5
F       A       0.1
```

so then, the expected result will be:

```
//file3.txt
SourceFile1  TargetFile1  SourceFile2  TargetFile2
A            B            A            B
A            C            B            C
B            A            B            A
C            B            C            B
C            D            C            D
C            E            D            C
D            A            D            E
E            A            E            A
                          E            C
                          F            A
```

I have tried to merge them but the result is still not as expected. Is it possible to merge them as expected result? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you try to merge them?  What was the result you got?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine Columns in CSV file using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189108/combine-columns-in-csv-file-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your logic should be something like this:

```
open file1
open file2
open output
while  file1.hasNext AND file2.hasNext
    if file1.hasNext
       rec1 = parse(file1.next)
    end if
    if file2.hasNext
       rec2 = parse(file2.next)
    end if
    build outputrec using data from rec1 and rec2
    write outputrec to output
 end while
 close file1
 close file2
 close output
```